# How to use if in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have below scenario

Raw data:

```
Item Price
1     1
1    -1
1     2
2     4
2    -3
2    -1
3     2
3    -1
```

Required output:

```
Item Price
1    2
3    1
```

I want sum of all price for each item, but I want to exclude those item which as sum of price as zero.

Comment: please do not post only a picture. Picture links can break and won't be useful in the future. Post the relevant code and detail the scenario in the body of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need an aggregate query, something like this:

```
SELECT
    [Item],
    SUM([Price])
FROM
    [dbo].[YourTable]
WHERE
    [Price] <> 0
GROUP BY
    [Item]
HAVING
    SUM([Price]) > 0
```

Use the WHERE clause for the raw data or the HAVING clause for a condition on the aggregate value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [HAVING()](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/having.php) clause :

```
SELECT t.item,sum(t.price) as total_price
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.item
HAVING sum(t.price) <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just filtering records, which is what WHERE and HAVING is for. IF is used for choosing between two values based on some condition, that's not what is needed here.

```
SELECT Item, SUM(Price) p
FROM table
GROUP BY Item
HAVING p != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly working query, tested with proper data:

```
SELECT item, sum(price) as total
FROM product
GROUP BY item
HAVING sum(price) <> 0
```